# Why is ajax 'post' not functioning?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I want to send data post to php site then print. **The php print is not working.** I already examined the other questions but nothing helpful. It will not work out. Why?

**JS** (working)

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://whatever.com/data.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  async: false,
  data: data
});
```

**PHP backend** (not working)

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
header('Content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
print_r($data); ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean **not functioning**? Can you please elaborate on that more? Thanks!

Comment: If I had to guess, you most likely need to `data: JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: @norbitrial i am sending data to php site. then i want to print that data. but thats not working. why?

Comment: Where are you expecting to see the printed data? I mean you never use it anywhere ...

Comment: @Teemu the site i sent the data to from the javascript

Comment: AJAX is for sending data to the server, and then the same AJAX receives the response from the server, without loading a new page. You've to do something with the response in JS, or drop the AJAX, and post a form instead.

Comment: PHP is server side code. Do you expect to see `data` printed on you screen in a browser? You need to log it somewhere

Comment: @T.Short But this: `<?php
$json = '["geeks", "for", "geeks"]';
$data = json_decode($json);
print_r($data);
?>` is the same php code and working, but when i specify i want to get data from request it is not working..

Comment: You need to use JSON.stringify(data) instead of direct data. As you are reading the rawBody of request. see my ansewer below

Comment: @vrvevvfsjjj — You say `<?php $json = '["geeks", "for", "geeks"]';` works. Does it work when you make the request with Ajax? Or are you making other changes?

Comment: What is the value of `data`? You should provide a [mcve]

Comment: `async: false,` is deprecated, causes performance problems, and should not be used.

Comment: @Quentin If you know a solution for this, you can find the whole javascript code here: https://jsfiddle.net/wkL8yo3a/1/ maybe you know the problem!

Comment: A glance at the code and it looks fine. Which brings us back to Teemu's point. Your PHP does nothing with the data except send it back to the client. Your JavaScript does nothing with the response. Where are you looking to see if this works or not?

Comment: @Quentin actually the php should simply just take the data from the request headers and then print it on the page. And i dont need a response in this case. I am testing this on input forms. Everything works, the request is sent off, except that nothing is printed. The javscript takes user input, saves in local storage then is sending it off to remote server

Comment: @vrvevvfsjjj — "actually the php should simply just take the data from the request headers and then print it on the page". No. That isn't how HTTP works.

Comment: @vrvevvfsjjj — "And i dont need a response in this case" — If you don't need a response, why do you have `print_r($data);` instead of `header("HTTP/1.1 204 NO CONTENT"); exit;`? (Hint: Because you need a response)

Comment: @vrvevvfsjjj — "except that nothing is printed" … because you have written no code to print it.

Comment: @Quentin I am new to php. The fact that `print_r` should print the information about a variable is a little bit misleading in this case. If you know what is missing, or how the php should look like, it would be nice if you share that!

Comment: @vrvevvfsjjj — It does print it… to STDOUT… so it gets put in the response and sent to the browser… where your JavaScript ignores it.

Comment: @Quentin okay, i got the point that i have to respond to the respond of the target within the javascript. But how do i then say that this data should be printed on the target page? For example: The script is on google.com, capturing user data, then sending this data to example.com and printing it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type a URL into the address bar of your browser, then the browser will make a request to that URL and render the response in the window (or just save it to a file if it is a type that it can't render in the window).

If you put an `<img src="http://example.com/some.jpeg" alt="">` in a page that is rendered in a browser window, then the browser will make a request to that URL and render the image it gets back at the point in the page. (Note that it doesn't replace the *whole* page with the image, its an `<img>` not a link).

If you use Ajax (via XMLHttpRequest, fetch, or a wrapper library like jQuery or axios) to make a request to a URL, then the browser will make a request to that URL and pass the response back to the JavaScript.

For anything to happen with that data afterwards: **You must write JavaScript that will do that.**

You aren't loading a new webpage in the browser window. You can't loading an image with an `<img>` element. You are fetching data with JavaScript. (Usually when people do this they will want to do something more interesting then either replacing the entire page with the data or appending the data to the very end of the page. There's no sensible default thing that could be done other than let the JavaScript author decide what do to with it).

Current versions of jQuery return a thenable object, so you can treat it as a promise to get the data from:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://whatever.com/data.php',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: data
}).then(function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

You'll probably want to do something more interesting than just alerting the response. [MDN has an introductory guide to manipulating documents with JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents).

> okay, i got the point that i have to respond to the respond of the target within the javascript. But how do i then say that this data should be printed on the target page? For example: The script is on google.com, capturing user data, then sending this data to example.com and printing it there.

This is getting increasingly unclear, but assuming you mean:

*When someone visits a page, JavaScript is used to make an HTTP request to a server. Later, when someone visits a page on that server, I want to show that data*

Then you need to store the data somewhere. Typically this would be in a database.

1. The JavaScript runs and POSTs data to the URL
2. The PHP at the URL inserts it into the database
3. Later someone visits a page on that server
4. The PHP looks in the database to see if there is any data there and includes it in the page

If, on the other hand, you mean:

*Someone is looking at a page (A). When someone visits a different page (B), JavaScript is used to make an HTTP request to a server. The data should be **immediately** shown on page A*

… then you should be looking into WebSockets as you'll need to push the data to the browser.

Comment: Ah okay! So all i had to do is to put the data in a database. I was thinking about just simply printing it on the page. As it seemed, with fetch() and node.js, node.js is just simply receiving the data without any database as i have seen in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kw5tC5nQMRY

Answer (score 0):

Last update, I guess using ajax is misleading you, instead you can create a form diretly through js and the post it, like this you'll have the php ansewer printed ...

in js:

```
var url = '/test.php'; // or https://whatever.com/data.php
var value = 'MTIzLGZlZg';
var form = $('<form action="' + url + '" method="post">' +
  '<input type="text" name="my_var" value="' + value + '" />' +
  '</form>');
$('body').append(form);
form.submit();
```

in php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
header('Content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
// now the posted value is in $_POST
echo $_POST['my_var']; 
?>
```

Comment: The 'data' is already stringified in the javascript code. That is just a snippet of the code. The php part is not working out..

Comment: Can you print_r $_POST global?

Comment: Can you try adding ini_set("allow_url_fopen", true) in php file? Cf update in my ansewer?

Comment: Tried, still not working. But thanks for the answer

Comment: Weired, is the json you are posting valid? Can you share the data value you are submitting?

Comment: This is the request payload that i am sending: `"MTIzLGZlZg"` it is a json string

Comment: wait ! are you waiting that the print_r shows in the xhr response ?

Comment: no, i am waiting that the data which is an array is printed on the website as specified

Comment: php wont print directly as you are calling it via ajax, instead you can get the value in success function and use it or print it, take a look at my ansewer update, and let me know if you have an alert with the payload value .

Comment: yes, thats working but it is useless because i really need to move the data from one website to the other then print it. but still thanks for the answer!

Comment: I guess then that "The php print is not working" statement is false. as it is working

Comment: it is working but only on the client side. i need to print the data on an external server with different domain..

Comment: see my update, I guess the fact you are using ajax is misleading you.
Can you try it and confirm if that's what you need ?

Comment: No, i think i am going to use fetch() for that operation, ajax doesnt wanna work out. But still thanks for the answers!

Comment: okay, anyway please next time try to be more explicit as the question "ajax post not working" and "php print not working" have nothing to do with your need, as they both were actually working ....

Comment: @vrvevvfsjjj — `fetch` is a tool to do Ajax with

Comment: @Quentin yes, but instead of using php to receive i am going to use node.js

Comment: @vrvevvfsjjj — That seems rather like having a spade which will work perfectly well if you use it correctly and replacing both the handle and the blade without identifying the actual problem.